# Using for loop to create series xlsx files in R

Tags: r, excel, for-loop

I have a dataset and want to split it into series xlsx files by a variable: "Block". 
I can write the code for exporting single block into one file, but I need to create them all at once. 
My current code is：

```
data_block1<-subset(data_name, Block %in% c(1))
data_block1$Detail<-data_Mf$Detail
write.xlsx(data_block1, "C:/block1.xlsx")
```

How can I transfer these scripts into for loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reproducible code provided and given what you've provided you can do the following:

```
for(i_block in Block) {
  tmp_df <- subset(data_name, Block %in% i_block)
  # tmp_df$Detail<-data_Mf$Detail     # why is this here and what does it do?
  write.xlsx(tmp_df, paste0("C:/block", i_block, ".xlsx"))
}
```

Comment: tmp_df$Detail<-data_Mf$Detail  is to add a variable into tmp_df. Your code works for me. Thank you very much!